# I have miktex but it can not recognize the xepersian package

Tags: miktex, xepersian, persian

I downloaded Miktex2.9 but when I try to type Farsi(persian) it does not recognize the xepersian package and give an error instead.
I need to add the xepersian or other packages to my Miktex please tell me how to do it.

Comment: How did you install Miktex? And welcome to TeX.SX!

Comment: I downloaded it from http://www.tug.org/protext/ and installed it as the protex.exe

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you installed MikTeX basic, which does not have `xepersian` included. One way to install `xepersian` is using mikTeX on-the-fly package install, but not recommended. There might be dependencies you miss.

The best solution I recommend is installing *Texlive 2013* and update it. Installing miktex (complete) is another solution, but you must make sure it contains latest `xetex` binaries. Older versions of miktex was shipped with old `xetex` binaries and caused some bugs in RTL typesetting.

Comment: The missing dependencies are detected, and the needed packages are installed, as well, at least in these cases when it happened here. Other than in TeX Live also the binaries are frequently updated, but, yes, back in past this did for some time not happen for XeTeX (and also LuaTeX).

Answer (score 0):

Open the MiKTeX Package Manager as Administrator; you'll see he whole list of packages in MiKTeX distribution. Right click on the `xepersian` package  (you may type "xepersian" in the small `Name` window at the top and `filter` the packages list) . A small menu will popup; choose "install". That's all. Any additional package can be installed in the same way.

Comment: Well,in case of several users,  to be sure that each of them can use the package. Thanks for pointing the typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the portable xepersian. This is very user frindly and no needs to instalation. The size of it is about !G.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more? You mean 1G instead of !G? BTW: Welcome to TeX.SE!